# PayPal payment wall not rendered - Error "Invalid approval URL"

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm integrating the `PayPal Plus` environment on our site. We are using the current version of `PayPal PHP SDK` (1.7.4) available on Github https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK. We are using `PHP` 7.0.7 on `IIS` 10.

First we create a payment as explained in the integration guide. We receive a valid approval url from the payment (format: 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=...).
I checked the url in the browser manually.

The payment is created in a controller and is given to the view.

Controller:

```
    function showPaymentWall() {
    $payment = $this->createPayment();
    return view("payments.paypal.paymentWall",['payment'=>$payment, 'approval_url'=> $this->approvalUrl]);
}
```

The `approval_url` is set in the method `createPayment`.

Here is the code from the view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title')
Upgrade
@endsection
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div>{{ $approval_url }}</div>
            <div id="ppplus"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
@endsection

@section('scriptIndividualJSCode')
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
     var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
        "approvalUrl": "{{ $approval_url }}",
        "placeholder": "ppplus",
        "mode": "sandbox",
        "country": "DE"
     });
</script>
@endsection
```

As you can see the valid url is displayed before the ppplus container. So that it is clear, that the url is valid and correctly given by the controller.
But when I visit the page, I always get this error:

[image]

When I check the reason via console it says "Invalid approval url".

[image]

Anybody an idea why or what I can check to get forward?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the reason after a long search.

It comes out, that the `&amp;` in the approval URL has to be replaced with `&`.
Then it worked. This can be done with the `PHP` function `htmlspecialchars_decode()` (see http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php). Here is my code for the `javascript` part:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
             var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
                "approvalUrl": "<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($approval_url); ?>",
                "placeholder": "ppplus",
                "mode": "sandbox",
                "country": "DE",
                "language": "de_DE"
             });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, saved me a lot of time. If someone works with `Symfony` and `Twig`, the following can be used to insert the `URL` in correct format: `{{ approval_url|raw }}